# Buffer and reduce values while switching to another observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

Let's say we have some `input$` observable which emits `Item`:

```js
const input$: Observable<Item>;
```

For each emission, I need to switch to another observable (akin to `switchMap`). However, I need to make sure that all of these switched observables complete and run in sequence. Easily enough, we have `concatMap` to achieve this:

```js
input$.pipe(concatMap(item => processItem(item)))
```

However, what I would like to do instead: buffer items and reduce them (i.e., I have a function `(a: Item, b: Item): Item`) whilst one of these switched observables is active. More specifically, assume `type Item = {[key: string]: string}`. My reducer would simply be `{...a, ...b}` in this case.

We have a lot of `buffer*`, `window*` and `throttle*` operators available, though I can't seem to find an *easy* combination to achieve this behavior.

I could very well write my custom operator, but I am interested in **whether it is instead possible to express this as a (simple-ish) combination of some built-in operators**?

Just to make it clear: the output observable should emit the value of the observable to which we switched, not the buffered/reduced values. Also, while completion / error of the source should be reflected in the output, any on-going inner subscription should finish first.

The operator I am looking for should essentially have a signature similar to

```js
bufferedConcatMap<T, R>(
    project: (value: T) => Observable<R>, 
    reducer: (values: T[]) => T
): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

---

For completeness sake, here's a marble diagram of the operator I am looking for. This assumes addition as a reducer and we just switch to the input, but with a delay of four ticks:

```
Input:  ---123--|
Output: ------1--(5|)
```

Here, the `1` is immediately switched to our delay (since there's no on-going inner subscription), and four ticks later we get the result. Since in the meantime, both `2` and `3` have been emitted, they are buffered together and reduced to `2 + 3 = 5`, which again is emitted four ticks later since we only switched to this after the `1` has come back.

Comment: Is an intermediate observable allowed? There is a way to do it with two observables subscribing to each other.. a buffer observable that uses another concat observable as closingNotifier which in turn uses the buffer notification (reduced) as its source notification.

Comment: @ggradnig That goes in the direction of what I was thinking of so far too, and at that point I think I'd just implement a fully custom operator instead anyway that manages the subscriptions. That said, feel free to post it as an answer anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 12/13**: Since I am under the operating assumption that a simple combination of built-in operators won't do the job here, I've implemented my own operator. Contrary to my original requirement, this behaves as follows:

- If the source completes, the output will first wait for an active inner subscription to complete before completing the outer observable.
- If the source errors, the outer observable will propagate the error immediately. This is more in line with operators like `concatMap` and `exhaustMap`.

I have yet to write a test suite for this, but so far it seems to be working fine.

I'll post the operator's code here, [you can also find a Stackblitz playground here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bufferreducemap?file=index.ts).

```js
type Reducer<A, B> = (values: A[]) => B;
type Project<A, B> = (value: A) => ObservableInput<B>;

export function bufferReduceMap<A, B, R>(reducer: Reducer<A, B>, project: Project<B, R>): OperatorFunction<A, R> {
  return function (source: Observable<A>) {
    return source.lift(new BufferReduceMapOperator<A, B, R>(reducer, project));
  };
}

class BufferReduceMapOperator<A, B, R> implements Operator<A, R> {

  constructor(private reducer: Reducer<A, B>, private project: Project<B, R>) {}

  call(subscriber: Subscriber<R>, source: any): TeardownLogic {
    return source.subscribe(new BufferReduceMapSubscriber<A, B, R>(subscriber, this.reducer, this.project));
  }

}

class BufferReduceMapSubscriber<A, B, R> extends OuterSubscriber<A, B> {

  private buffer: A[] = [];
  private active = false;
  private hasCompleted = false;
  private hasErrored = false;

  constructor(
    destination: Subscriber<R>,
    private reducer: Reducer<A, B>,
    private project: Project<B, R>,
  ) {
    super(destination);
  }

  protected _next(value: A) {
    const buffer = this.buffer;
    buffer.push(value);

    this._tryNext();
  }

  protected _complete() {
    this.hasCompleted = true;
    if (!this.active && this.buffer.length === 0) {
      this.destination.complete();
    }

    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  public notifyComplete(innerSub: Subscription) {
    this.remove(innerSub);

    this.active = false;
    if (this.buffer.length !== 0) {
      this._tryNext();
    } else if (this.hasCompleted) {
      this.destination.complete();
    }
  }

  protected _tryNext() {
    if (this.active) {
      return;
    }

    let reduced: B;
    try {
      reduced = this.reducer(this.buffer);
    } catch (err) {
      this.destination.error(err);
      return;
    }

    let result: ObservableInput<R>;
    try {
      result = this.project(reduced);
    } catch (err) {
      this.destination.error(err);
      return;
    }

    this.active = true;

    const innerSubscriber = new InnerSubscriber(this, undefined, undefined);

    const destination = this.destination as Subscription;
    destination.add(innerSubscriber);

    this.buffer = [];
    subscribeTo<R>(result)(innerSubscriber);
  }

}
```